# Why does the Method Resolution Order effect the behavior of my code?

Tags: python, class

I was looking into how the order in which you declare classes to inherit from affects Method Resolution Order ([Detailed Here](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) By Raymond Hettinger). I personally was using this to elegantly create an Ordered Counter via this code:

```
class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass

counts = OrderedCounter([1, 2, 3, 1])

print(*counts.items())

>>> (1, 2) (2, 1) (3, 1)
```

I was trying to understand why the following didn't work similarly:

```
class OrderedCounter(OrderedDict, Counter):
    pass

counts = OrderedCounter([1, 2, 3, 1])

print(*counts.items())

>>> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

While I understand that on a fundamental level this is because the OrderedCounter object is using the OrderedDict.__init__() function in the second example which according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) only accepts "[items]". In the first example however the Counter.__init__() function is used which according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) accepts "[iterable-or-mapping]" thus it can take the list as an input.

I wanted to further understand this interaction specifically though so I went to look at the actual [source](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/collections.py). When I looked at the OrderedDict.__init__() function I noticed that after some error handling it made a call to `self.update(*args, **kwds)`. However, the code simply has the line `update = MutableMapping.update` which I can't find much documentation on.

I guess I would just like a more concrete answer as to why the second code block doesn't work.

**Note**: For context, I have a decent amount of programming experience but I'm new to python and OOP *in Python*

**TLDR**: How/Why does the Method Resolution Order interfere with the second code block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example, `class OrderedCounter(OrderedDict, Counter):` the object  looks in OrderedDict first which uses the update method from MutableMapping.

MutableMapping is an Abstract Base Class in [collections._abc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html). Its update method source is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L824). You can see that if the `other` argument is not a mapping it will try to iterate over `other` unpacking a key and value on each iteration.

```
        for key, value in other:
            self[key] = value
```

If `other` is a sequence of tuples it would work.

```
>>> other = ((1,2),(3,4))
>>> for key,value in other:
    print(key,value)
    
1 2
3 4
>>>
```

But if `other` is a sequence of *single items* it will throw the error when it tries to unpack a single value into two names/variables.

```
>>> other = (1,2,3,4)
>>> for key,value in other:
    print(key,value)
    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#50>", line 1, in <module>
    for key,value in other:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
>>>
```

---

Whearas collections.Counter's [update method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L608) calls a different function if `other` is not a Mapping.

```
        else:
            _count_elements(self, iterable)
```

[_count_elements](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L478) adds keys for new items (with a count of zero) or adds one to the count of existing keys.

---

As you probably discovered if a class inherits from two classes it will look in the *first* class to find an attribute, if it isn't there it will look in the *second* class.

```
>>> class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def f(self):
        print('class A')

        
>>> class B:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def f(self):
        print('class B')

>>> class C(A,B):
    pass

>>> c = C()
>>> c.f()
class A

>>> class D(B,A):
    pass

>>> d = D()
>>> d.f()
class B
```

Answer (score 0):

In mro, children precede their parents and the order of appearance in `__bases__` is respected.

In the first example, Counter is a subclass of dict. When OrderedDict is provided along with Counter, the parent dict of Counter is replaced by OrderedDict and the code works seamlessly.

In the second example, OrderedDict is again a subclass of dict. When Counter is provided along with OrderedDict, it tries to replace the parent dict of OrderedDict with Counter, which is counter intuitive (pun intended). Hence the error!!

I hope this layman explaination helps you. Just think about that for a moment.

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite understand why you consider the second example counter-intuitive while the first one apparently isn't. Both Counter and OrderedDict are subclasses of dict so I don't see where the distinction comes from.